# Compare two arrays and echo difference

Tags: php

What is wrong with this code? I've tried using `array_udiff` without any success.

```
<?php
#I want to echo values of $paths1 that do not appear (even partially) on $paths2.

$paths1 = array('one', 'two', 'three');
$paths2 = array('twenty one', 'twenty two');

foreach ($paths1 as $path1)
    {
    foreach ($paths2 as $path2)
        {
        if (stripos($path1, $path2) == False)
            {
            echo $path1 . "<br>";
            break;
            }
        }
    echo "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Always usev boolean === false when checking for needle not found. http://us.php.net/strpos

Comment: Getting the same result...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to use `stripos() === false`, as if they match it's going to return `0` which is == to `false`.
2. You have your parameters mixed, it should be `stripos($path2, $path1)`.
3. You need to check all values in `$paths2` until you find one it is in.  You are saying it's not in any `$paths2` after the first one you don't find it in.  Set a flag of `$flag = true;` between the `foreach()` loops.  Instead of echoing inside the second foreach, just set `$flag == false` if `stripos($path2, $path1) !== false`. After the second loop ends, but before the first, output if `$flag == false`.

ie

```
foreach ($paths1 as $path1)
{
    $flag = true;
    foreach ($paths2 as $path2)
    {
         if (stripos($path2, $path1) !== false)
         {
             $flag = false;
             break;
         }
    }
    if($flag)
        echo $path1;
}
```

Note: didn't test it, but should work.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments to [`stripos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) are backwards.  Instead of:

```
if (stripos($path1, $path2) == False)
```

You want:

```
if (stripos($path2, $path1) === false)
```